# How to Connect several Google Spreadsheets tabs to BigQuery

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

It may seem that Google Spreadsheets only exposes the first tab (you can reorder them though) to BigQuery.

I have several tables, taking data ones from the others making several calculations already, being configured by params, in the same Spreadsheet but different tabs.

How can I read other tabs than the first one from Google Spreadsheets to BigQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Bigquery can only read from the first tab.  See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive.

There is an open issue in the Issue Tracker asking for this feature, you could add a "me too" to it?  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905674.  There is also a work around posted on here which may help

Alternatively, you could write something using AppScript to export the data from the sheet into a BigQuery table (this may help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#load_csv_data)

Answer (score 3):

You can now specify the sheet and/or range of a Google Sheet in the new BigQuery UI which you would like to use as your federated data source.
To Quote from documentation:

> Optionally indicate which sheet and cell range in the Google Sheets
>   spreadsheet to create a table from. You can specifiy: [sheet_title]
>   for the whole sheet, or
>   [sheet_title]![top_left_cell_id]:[bottom_right_cell_id]for a
>   rectangular cell range in a sheet, such as "Sheet1!A1:B20". When this
>   is not specified, the first sheet in the spreadsheet is used.

or You can use CLI as:

```
{   "autodetect": false,   "sourceFormat": "GOOGLE_SHEETS",    "sourceUris": [     "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"   ],   "maxBadRecords": 1,   "googleSheetsOptions":   {     "range": "test_sheet!A1:B20",     "skipLeadingRows": 0   } }
```

Comment: FYI the documentation referred to in the answer is https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive

Comment: @Priya Agarwal - If cell range is provided while creating table, how will BQ react when new data is added in Google Sheets?

Comment: @AdilK - Then also the table will show only the data from defined cell range.